# Kext Code sign error in Mavericks

Tags: macos, code-signing, osx-mavericks, kernel-extension

We have a audio kernel extension, which installs in /Library/Extensions.
According apple new guidelines(WWDC video 707) we should code sign kext which installs  /Library/Extensions.
We requested apple to enable kext code signing attribute to our developer id and now it is enabled. As per the mail reply that we got from apple says like this

If you have previously obtained a Developer ID for application signing, you need to re-download your Developer ID to have the updated certificate.

Hence we redownloded certificate and codesigned the kext. Code compiles fine However when we try to verify the code sign using below command
sudo kextutil -tn KEXTPATH

it gives following error-
Code Signing Failure: code signature is invalid
KEXT_PATH appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries).

Can any one help me to resolve this error.

Comment: try doing `sudo kextutil -v KEXTPATH` and see what the output indicates. also try `codesign -dvvv KEXTPATH` and `codesign --verify -vvvv` to determine more about your codesignature.

Comment: Thanks.I will try these commands

Comment: Also ensure you are using `codesign` from XCode 3.5 or (preferably) 4.x. Older XCode versions may have problems to sign kexts.

Comment: @mity you're thinking of 4.5 and 5.x, but your point is otherwise correct: the devtools for 4.4 and earlier don't produce correctly signed kexts. Also make sure your command-line tools are being invoked in the correct version (cf `xcrun`)

Comment: @pmjordan: Yep, you are right. 4.5 or 5.x.

Comment: Hey @Sprabhu, have you found the solution?

Comment: @MattyAyOh Yes. This issue was due to developer id certificate.We have created new developer id certificate as mentioned in WWDC video 707.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the developer ID certificate for the code signing of kexts to work you need to code sign kernel extensions on 10.9 and above.

You cannot sign it on 10.8, install it on 10.9 -> /Library/Extensions

I am not sure if this helps solve your problem.